# Angular / SCSS - Style deep nested div in component

Tags: angular, sass

I have a parent container with nested components, one of the nested components uses ag-grid. I need to override the style of .ag-cell, but I'm not sure how, I tried the following, but it did not work:

**parent:**

```
<div class="grid-typeahead-container">
    <me-typeahead-simple-control></me-typeahead-simple-control>
</div>
```

**me-typeahead-simple-control:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label *ngIf="label">{{ label }}</label>

    <div class="input-group ms-search-control mcl-typeahead">
        <input class="form-control typeahead-simple-input"
               [(ngModel)]="selectedLabel"
               [typeahead]="optionsList"
               ...
               #elem
        >
    </div>
</div>
```

**scss:**

```
.grid-typeahead-container {
  .ag-cell {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't appear to have any `.ag-cell` elements in your HTML - but assuming they're children of your `.grid-typeahead-container`, the SCSS should target them correctly.

Comment: try :host>>>  .grid-typeahead-container {
  .ag-cell {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}

Comment: Have you tried applying your styles using ::ng-deep ..ag-cell { }   inside your me-typeahead-simple-control.scss  ?

Comment: I can't change the actual typeahead since it's used elsewhere, I need to override the styles in this particular page only. The .ag-cell is in a child component, but the styles are not holding for some reason. I have not tried to ng-deep yet, but I'll give it a shot.